# Linux - Outgoing connections from process timeout after the process restarts

Tags: ubuntu, tcp, linux-networking

banging my head against the wall with this one...

I have an Ubuntu Linux server, on top of which our own process which holds 40K persistent connections to external services.

When the process starts, it tries to reconnect to the 40K external endpoints. When I restart the process after long activity, and it tries to reconnect, **most of the reconnects fail by timing out**. About an hour after the initial restart, the connection attempts are suddenly succeeding again.

Here's what I know:

1. Since the process restarts between the attempts, it cannot be the process' internal state
2. The external services are available regardless of my restart.
3. This leaves us with the server itself

My theory is that something in the Linux networking stack is being maxed out during steady state operation of our process, and only released after a significant timeout.

1. Which resource could be maxed out, and how can I verify this scenario?
2. Is there an alternative explanation?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you behind a NAT ? Where are these external services hosted ? Is the stop process actually closing properly the connections ?

Comment: The server is on Amazon, the stop process is not closing the connections gracefully, a crash or kill -9 is a good example.